# How to mock a variable within a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I want to test a function in Node.js.

My test will pass some parameters to the function and I will check what the function returns.

In the function there is a variable which runs another function. I'd like to
mock what this variable is set to. Is that possible and if so, how is it done? I've hit on sinon and am trying to figure out if anything can be done with it.

This is the function:

```
    users.listUsers = async (params, db) => {
        const { sName, sEmail } = params;
        let { sortBy, descending } = params;
        const { offset = 0, limit = 20 } = params;

        // Users
        const query = db.knex.select([
          'users.id',
          'users.name',
          'users.email',
          'sup.id as sup_id',
          'sup.title',
        ]).from('users')
          .count('cus_users.id')
          .leftJoin('sup_users', 'users.id', 'sup_users.user_id')
          .innerJoin('sup', 'sup.id', 'sup_users.sup_id')
          .innerJoin('cus', 'cus.sup_id', 'sup.id')
          .leftJoin('cus_users', function additionalAnd() {
            this.on('cus.id', 'cus_users.cus_id')
              .andOn('users.id', 'cus_users.user_id');
          })
          .groupByRaw('users.id, users.name, users.email, sup.id, sup.title');

        if (sName) {
          query.where('users.name', 'ILIKE', `%${sName}%`);
        }
        if (sEmail) {
          query.where('users.email', 'ILIKE', `%${sEmail}%`);
        }

        if (sortBy && descending) {
          sortBy = ORDER_FIELDS.indexOf(sortBy) !== -1 ? sortBy : null;
          descending = String(descending).toLowerCase() === 'true' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
          query.orderBy(sortBy, descending);
        }
        if (offset && limit) {
          query.offset(offset).limit(limit);
        }

        let users = await query.offset(offset).limit(limit);

        users = users.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
          if (accumulator[item.id]) {
            const group = accumulator[item.id];
            group.sup.push({
              id: item.sup_id,
              code: item.code,
              title: item.title,
            });
            group.count = `${(+group.count) + (+item.count)}`;
          } else {
            accumulator[item.id] = item;
            accumulator[item.id].sup = [];
            accumulator[item.id].sup.push({
              id: item.sup_id,
              code: item.code,
              title: item.title,
            });
            delete accumulator[item.id].sup_id;
            delete accumulator[item.id].code;
            delete accumulator[item.id].title;
          }
          return accumulator;
        }, {});

        users = Object.values(users);
        return users;
      };
```

Currently it fails on `const query = db.knex.select([` as it returns undefined. I need to set that to something. I don't think it matters what as I then want to also set `users` to a specific value which I'll then use to determine and check for the correct response in my test. I'm not yet sure if this can be done but if it can I want to find out how to do it.

Comment: Hi @runnerpaul, please share some codes get a better understanding about the problem.

Comment: @deerawan I added some additional information to the question.

Comment: You should look at creating a proxy class/function that can be injected. You can pass in a mock, while your production code would use the proxy version that actually uses knex.